# How to show Month and also weekday in three letters from date

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I am getting a date from server like this

```
2016-02-10
```

and I want to show a date on my view like this

```
 TUE, 10 FEB 2016
```

How can I do this

here is my code of getting a date

```
let departureDate  = (((dict["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Trip"] as?NSDictionary)!["departure_date"] as?NSString)! as String
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do like

```
//create dateformatter
let dateFormatter2 = NSDateFormatter()

// set your dateformat intially whatever u get from server or local
                          //2016-02-10
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

// convert your string to date
let date2 = dateFormatter2.dateFromString(departureDate as String)

 // create another dateformat for what output u need at final
                           // TUE, 10 FEB 2016
 dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy"
 // again convert the date to string again 
 let finaldate = dateFormatter2.stringFromDate(date2!).uppercaseString
```

iPhone format strings are in [Unicode format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: hello Thanks for your answer. It is working.. could you tell me how can I show all in caps.?

Comment: @hellosheikh -- show all in caps , can you show for example

Comment: `let finaldate = dateFormatter2.stringFromDate(date2!).uppercaseString`. Note also that `StringFromdate` should be `stringFromDate` (camelCase method names), and that `date2` is an optional that needs to be unwrapped (possibly use an `if let` clause rather than my example with forced unwrapping here).

Comment: okay thank you and also edit your answer. last line should be like this 
 let finaldate = dateFormatter2.stringFromDate(date2). actually I am saying so future users don't get confuse

Comment: @Thank you very much